# Using "=>" operator in C#

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I got a code from Internet which contains below line of code

```
protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() => new ExponentialDoubleAnimation();
```

I don't have installed this version of C# in visual studio. so this is showing error that "Missing ;".
can anybody please tell me what will be the similar code in c# 5 and below for this line of code?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I've edited your duplicate list since expression body members are not lambda expressions.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks, I forgot to remove the wrong one

Answer (score 5):

C#6 (and later versions, of course) supports [expression body methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#methods). It's a shorter equivalent to:

```
protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore() 
{
    return new ExponentialDoubleAnimation();
}
```